# How to access from user control to its child form?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a child form that displays with a button in user control and I want to clone ListView in user control to its child form.

I checked with breakpoint and printed the list but it gives me error like out of bounds or instance variable is zero.

```
public partial class JobForm: Form
{
    public Job()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    List<string> joblist = new List<string>();
    public List<string> _var
    {

        set {

            joblist = value; }
    }

}
```

User Control

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(_var[0].ToString());      
    JobForm jb = new JobForm();
    jb.Show();
}
public List<string> listViewJob()
{
    _var.Add(item);
    return _var;
}
public List<string> _var { get;} = new List<string>();
```

I used also 'var parent = this.Parent as JobForm; parent.ID2 = ID2; but it gives me same error. So I check with breakpoint it is a correct list until the form shows then I get null or out of bound (_var) in User Control and in Form. I would appreciate if you could write an example.

Comment: Are you using usercontrol in `JobForm` ?

Comment: Where does `item` come from?

Comment: No I have another form which is main for and have tabpages(one of them is this user control). 

There is a function returns item which I have not written the function here :) as long as it works

Answer (score 0):

It is very confusing that both `JobForm` and the user control have a list called `_var`. Its best to use more descriptive variable names.

I'm not completely sure what you want to achieve, but basically, when you have created the child form you can access its properties.

For instance:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(_var[0].ToString());      
    JobForm jb = new JobForm();

    // Members of 'jb' are available here
    this._var = jb._var;

    jb.Show();
}
```

Comment: Yes but the problem I have to access user control with User1 user = new User1(); maybe here I should access existing user control instead of to create a new one.

Comment: @JuanRodre Please add that peace of code to your original post to clarify the problem.